What's the meaning of "wholeness" here?
Does the word "wholeness" here refer to the all parts of that auditorium including spectators, boxers, managers? Or could it simply refer to the atmosphere of the auditorium?

He thought only of his posture, of maintaining his position beside Ernie, of the steps he was mounting to the ring, of the ropes he was then spreading, sitting on the middle strand as he raised the rope above for Ernie and Babe to duck under. As he bustled, administered and directed, he was functioning at his best and he felt again the soaring, yet controlled, excited wholeness, periodically his, that he thought of as his true self.

Thanks in advance.

The whole paragraph describes only the boxer.  Hence wholeness primarily refers to him.

... he felt ... the ... wholeness ... his true self

This noun could apply also to the staff of each individual team, but maybe to a lesser extent than to the boxer as there are no descriptions on the staff.
Collins Dictionary defines wholeness: Wholeness is the quality of being complete or a single unit and not broken or divided into parts.
There are no descriptions of the mood of the spectators, so we can’t say this noun applies to them: there are usually clear lines between the supporters.  (This would be different in a political rally.)
I agree with Peter that wholeness doesn’t refer to the spectators in the current context.

It definitely doesn't refer to the spectators, because wholeness is linked to and defined by the subordinate clause. The wholeness is his true self. They are effectively synonyms.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick.  Agreed.

@PeterKirkpatrick thank you so much.

@SeowjoohengSingapore. Thank you very much.

Wholeness here is the emotional state of the boxer himself.  Wholeness philosophically is a state of psychological and spiritual completeness characterized by feeling fully realized and authentic, with a harmony among one's values, actions, and core identity.
Nothing to do with his environment or the venue.
